# Flashbots Inclusion of a Mempool Signed Transaction

Tags: txpool, flashbots, mev, mev-searcher

Hello i'm trying to understand how flashbots Bundles are working.
So far i can send a flashbots Bundle with several transactions that i made. But in the official docs it is stated that we can include a transaction from the mempool this way:

```
{
  signedTransaction: SIGNED_ORACLE_UPDATE_FROM_PENDING_POOL // serialized signed transaction hex
}
```

What is exactly this SIGNED_ORACLE_UPDATE_FROM_PENDING_POOL?

I tried in every way possible to serialize a signed transaction but i cannot make it work. Obviously the serializeTransaction from ethers.js cannot serialize a signed tx and even with ethereumjs/tx i cannot get this value.

I am sorry if there is something obvious here that i didn't understand but i've been trying to understand this for 2 days full time now, i could really use a little help :)

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. So i ever someone else is having the same issue, you need to get the raw tx before trying to serialize.

That was all :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your code for solving the problem? I have also encountered this problem, which has been causing me a headache for two days